# Git deleted my files after a failed branch switch

Tags: git, github, version-control

Normally I would work on a local branch called `test` and then merge that branch into `master` once the feature is completed. However, for one reason or another I lost my latest changes.

Here is what I did:

```bsh
T:\Test [test × +4 ~3 -5 !]> git status
On branch test
Your branch is based on 'origin/test', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   jest.config.js
        modified:   ormconfig.ts
        modified:   src/index.ts
        deleted:    src/it-portal/entity/Kiwi.ts
        deleted:    src/it-portal/entity/Movie.ts
        deleted:    src/it-portal/entity/User.ts
        deleted:    src/resolvers/HelloWorldResolver.ts
        deleted:    src/resolvers/MovieResolver.test.ts
        deleted:    src/resolvers/MovieResolver.ts
        deleted:    src/tests/Interfaces/global.d.ts
        deleted:    src/tests/config/globalSetup.ts
        deleted:    src/tests/config/globalTeardown.ts
        deleted:    src/tests/config/setupFiles.ts

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        src/it-portal/entity/Account.ts
        src/resolvers/AccountResolver.test.ts
        src/resolvers/AccountResolver.ts
        src/test-utils/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

T:\Test [test × +4 ~3 -10 !]> git add .

T:\Test [test × +4 ~7 -6 ~]> git commit -am 'added Account entity and resolvers'
[test caaa67a] added Account entity and resolvers
 17 files changed, 164 insertions(+), 183 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 src/it-portal/entity/Account.ts
 delete mode 100644 src/it-portal/entity/Kiwi.ts
 delete mode 100644 src/it-portal/entity/Movie.ts
 delete mode 100644 src/it-portal/entity/User.ts
 create mode 100644 src/resolvers/AccountResolver.test.ts
 create mode 100644 src/resolvers/AccountResolver.ts
 delete mode 100644 src/resolvers/HelloWorldResolver.ts
 delete mode 100644 src/resolvers/MovieResolver.test.ts
 delete mode 100644 src/resolvers/MovieResolver.ts
 rename src/{tests => test-utils}/Interfaces/global.d.ts (100%)
 rename src/{tests => test-utils}/config/globalSetup.ts (100%)
 rename src/{tests => test-utils}/config/globalTeardown.ts (100%)
 rename src/{tests => test-utils}/config/setupFiles.ts (100%)
 create mode 100644 src/test-utils/helpers/axios.ts

T:\Test [test ×]> git checkout master
fatal: cannot create directory at 'src/resolvers': Permission denied

T:\Test [test × +3 ~3 -8 !]> git merge test
Already up to date.

T:\Tes [test × +3 ~3 -8 !]> git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        jest.config.js
        ormconfig.ts
        src/index.ts
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        src/it-portal/entity/Kiwi.ts
        src/it-portal/entity/Movie.ts
        src/it-portal/entity/User.ts
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting

T:\Test [test × +3 ~3 -8 !]> git log
commit caaa67ae6643b5efa2c7f3bd65a3aa4317037367 (HEAD -> test)
Author: Me <bob@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 18 14:25:10 2020 +0200

    added Account entity and resolvers

commit 724bb33f38f3c380ac07666f0f6c3e5ca8648d8f (origin/master, master)
Author: Me <bob@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 17 15:27:14 2020 +0200

T:\Test [test × +3 ~3 -8 !]> git status
On branch test
Your branch is based on 'origin/test', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   jest.config.js
        modified:   ormconfig.ts
        modified:   src/index.ts
        deleted:    src/it-portal/entity/Account.ts
        deleted:    src/resolvers/AccountResolver.test.ts
        deleted:    src/resolvers/AccountResolver.ts
        deleted:    src/test-utils/Interfaces/global.d.ts
        deleted:    src/test-utils/config/globalSetup.ts
        deleted:    src/test-utils/config/globalTeardown.ts
        deleted:    src/test-utils/config/setupFiles.ts
        deleted:    src/test-utils/helpers/axios.ts

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        src/it-portal/entity/Kiwi.ts
        src/it-portal/entity/Movie.ts
        src/it-portal/entity/User.ts

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

T:\Test [test × +3 ~3 -8 !]> git branch
  master
* test
```

I noticed something went wrong while switching to the `master` branch. But now, although I did the correct commit in test, and still being on the branch `test` it's not showing me the added files like `Account.ts` and still showing me the removed files like `Kiwi.ts`. Any idea on how to fix this?

Also check the below, this is showing what I don't want to happen.

```bsh
T:\Test [test × +3 ~3 -8 !]> git checkout test
Switched to branch 'test'
M       jest.config.js
M       ormconfig.ts
M       src/index.ts
D       src/it-portal/entity/Account.ts
D       src/resolvers/AccountResolver.test.ts
D       src/resolvers/AccountResolver.ts
D       src/test-utils/Interfaces/global.d.ts
D       src/test-utils/config/globalSetup.ts
D       src/test-utils/config/globalTeardown.ts
D       src/test-utils/config/setupFiles.ts
D       src/test-utils/helpers/axios.ts
Your branch is based on 'origin/test', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
```

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, leading me to think that maybe something in Git has become corrupted.  +1 to you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens:

1. `git checkout master` failed due to `Permission denied`. You may have created the new files with a more privileged users than your or the permissions on those files have been altered/corrupted for some reasons.
   Git was not able to perform the required changes to switch the branch and restore the working tree of the `master` branch.
2. `git merge test` did not have any effect. You never switched the branch and you already were on `test` branch.
3. The second `git checkout master` warned you of uncommitted changes and stopped the switch branch command.
4. `git log` showed you the commit you did. This is a guarantee your work is not lost and a confirm you were on the `test` branch.
5. `git status` showed you a messed up working tree.
   That working tree is the result of the first `git checkout master` (at point 1).
   In an usual scenario, when a `git checkout` is not possible due to a dirty working tree, git stops the operation, restores the working tree and shows the user the reasons it cannot change the branch, as it happened in point 3 (the second `git checkout`).

Most probably, the first `git checkout` was not able to restore the working tree as it not had the correct permissions to create folders, resulting in a messed up working tree.

You have a lot of methods to restore the working tree to the last commit in the current branch.
I suggest you to `git reset --hard HEAD` to fully restore the working tree of your `test` branch and to check any permission issues on files and resolve it before to attempt any checkout or merge command.